# Xamarin файловая система

Tags: android, c#, uwp, xamarin, файловая-система

Не могу найти в Android/UWP где находятся сохраненные файлы

Реализовал сохранение/открытие файлов по [примеру](https://metanit.com/sharp/xamarin/6.1.php).
Всё успешно сохраняется, в каталоге эти файлы остаются  после завершения программы, но я **не могу их найти вне программы!** Пытался найти через поисковик и на Android, и в windows 10(UWP), но такого файла нигде нет. Что на Android-e, что в windows показ скрытых файлов включен

В коде в Android получение всех файлов из директории выглядит так:

```
IEnumerable<string> filenames = from filepath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments))
                                        select Path.GetFileName(filepath);
```

К слову, когда пытался посмотреть что есть среди музыки(изменил `SpecialFolder.MyDocuments` на `SpecialFolder.MyMusic`), то получил ошибку на Android с такой директорией:'/data/user/0/com.companyname.TestNavigationPage2/files/Music'

Вот такую папку "/com.companyname.TestNavigationPage2/files/" на Android нашел, но там имеется лишь .*override* , внутри которого лежат библиотеки и ресурсы(ресурсов нет)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments это специальная папка, закрытая для просмотра из вне. Этакое закрытое хранилище (Все что было в приложении, останется в приложении).
По поводу MyMusic - сейчас не могу сказать на 100, но не все папки из этого списка доступны на всех платформах.

К примеру то, то описано для iOS не работает точно так же на Android. и если MyDocuments пример закрытого хранилища, то в iOS к ней можно добраться через iTunes. (но это дополнительные настройки)

Comment: Скажите, а я могу как либо открыть доступ к этим файлам хотя бы на Android? В случае iOS понятно из политики, что этого сделать нельзя(разве что через iTunes получить к ним доступ)

Comment: @StriBog как простой пример, попытайтесь записать файл на флеш.  var myFile = new File("/sdcard/myFile.txt"); не забдьте добавить разрегения в манифесте на чтение и запись внешнего хранилища